# GhostScript: Cropping multiple area of pdf in single reading?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, ghostscript

I need to crop certain [multiple time with different area] area of pdf and save it as image. For that i am using the below commands in my windows system for ghostscript[9.5]:

```
    "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.50\bin\gswin64c.exe" ^
-dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE  ^
-dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 ^
-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=238 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=149.5 ^
-dFIXEDMEDIA -r600  -dDownScaleFactor=2 -sDEVICE=jpeg -o out1.jpeg ^
-c "<</PageOffset [ -64.2 40 ]>> setpagedevice" ^
-sPDFPassword=01011977 ^
-f "E:\PDFs\ECC\PDF_AESTRO.pdf"

"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.50\bin\gswin64c.exe" ^
-dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE  ^
-dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 ^
-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=238 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=149.5 ^
-dFIXEDMEDIA -r600  -dDownScaleFactor=2 -sDEVICE=jpeg -o out2.jpeg ^
-c "<</PageOffset [ -308.5 40 ]>> setpagedevice" ^
-sPDFPassword=01011977 ^
-f "E:\PDFs\ECC\PDF_AESTRO.pdf"
```

the above command does their job and crops both part from that pdf. 
But this is rendering the same pdf twice for that work and consuming the time and i want to save that time for faster processing as this will be used in firebase funciton for myweb app.

How can i crop both area to image in single reading of pdf?

Answer (score 1):

To be blunt about it; you can't do what you are asking. To get the same file rendered differently you need to render it each different way you want it rendered.

In passing; you no longer need to specify `-dSAFER` (since the 9,50 release) because that's the default. If you specify `-o` (instead of `-sOutputFile`) as you have done, then you don't need `-dBATCH` or `-dNOPAUSE`, `-o` includes both of those.

Personally I wouldn't bother with the GraphicsAlphaBits or TextAlphaBits given that you are rendering to JPEG, but that's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I used to do the work with an desktop application which i created earlier using Debeneu Lib and in that i just have to render/load the pdf once and can modify as needed and it does workout for me for what i am asking for. But as i will be trying to use this in my web app so the performance is needed and it could save up-to couple of seconds. And thank you for the information about `-dSafer -dBatch and -dNoPause` as it really made difference as i removed them. But for`Graphics and TextAlphaBits` i used them as they work like anti-aliasing for the texts and images.